# Hamburger icon on Toolbar acts as back button

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, androidx

I have tried to implement navigation drawer in my app with androidx library. So far, the app show hamburger icon on top left corner, but to access the drawer I have to swipe right. If I clicked the icon it will go to previous activity instead. Is it because this activity is not the main activity? How can I fix this? Thank you in advance.

Here is my activity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle t = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,R.string.Open, R.string.Close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(t);
        t.syncState();

        NavigationView nv = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        nv.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            switch(id)
            {
                case R.id.action_open_list:
                    break;
                case R.id.action_closed_list:
                    Intent closedListIntent = new Intent(this, ClosedListActivity.class);
                    startActivity(closedListIntent);
                    break;
                default:
                    return true;
            }


            return true;

        });
    }
```

my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_error_message_display"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="@string/error_message_cannot_connect"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pb_loading_indicator"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </FrameLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Where is your `toolbar` in your layout? To work your `toolbar` should be child of `drawer layout`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Toolbar` needs to be a child of `DrawerLayout` to work with.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_error_message_display"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="@string/error_message_cannot_connect"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/pb_loading_indicator"
                android:layout_width="42dp"
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Then in your Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id. drawerLayout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle t = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.Open, R.string.Close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(t);
    t.syncState();

    ....
}
```